# C++ Run-time Preempting Stack-Overflows

Tags: c++, recursion, memory, stack-overflow

I'm trying to write a library which can parse end user files to be used for adding some simple user generated content into a project and I want to try and make the library as flexible as possible. I use recursion for the tokenisation process of 'objects' which goes through a chain of four functions but I am conflicted with how to handle the potential situation of an end user going nested object happy. I know I can set a hard limit on how many times the program can recurse but I would like to make it as flexible as possible. Is there any way that I can calculate the (maximum - 1) number of times that this process can execute so that I can preempt a stack overflow error and return an error or something to be handled?

Comment: Any recursion can be rewritten as iteration plus explicit stack. This way you are not limited by call stack size, but only by available memory on the system.

Comment: The C++ standard does not specify the means for determining the available stack space needed for a recursive function call, nor the amount of stack space available to a process.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That sounds interesting and a good way to go. The functions in the chain preform a number of checks and some such and return information back up the chain. Would you be able to point me at any tutorials or articles that talk about a possible implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way that I can calculate the (maximum - 1) number of times that this [recursive] process can execute ...

No. It's not even guaranteed that each stack frame in the call chain is the same size.

Transforming a recursive implementation to an iterative one is fairly simple and really well-defined: you just

1. replace the implicit call stack (and function call operation) with an explicit state container, such as `std::stack<State>`
2. instead of a recursive call, you push the new call's `State` onto your stack, and continue the loop
3. instead of being called, the loop starts by popping the current `State` off the stack, and processes that, which may require pushing another new `State` on there if you would previously have made another recursive call

Alternatively, you can just split your current recursive descent parser into a tokenizer and LALR (or similar) parser, which are both iterative in the first place. You can generate these with Flex and Bison (Lex/Yacc), for example.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you can use the SEH framework to catch the stack overflow exception using __try/__except and exit your program.
However, if your application is using C++ then you would need to compile using /EHa or /EHsc flag. 
Check this link for more details on using SEH with C\C++ and the specifics of using /EHa and /EHsc flags.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/structured-exception-handling-c-cpp

```
__try  
{  
    //code which might generate stack overflow  
}  
__except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)  
{  
    //handle stack overflow exception, throw error and exit program     
}
```

Hope this helps!